# Add more and remove fieldset

Tags: 7

I created one content typa and I put one fieldset group through [Field_group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module, but I can't see settings to add more fieldset. I've 6 fields per fieldset. But I'm not able to do the same with fieldset. It can be done with particular field only.

Answer (score 0):

You can add more fieldset by Add new group option available in Manage field page, please find the below screenshot.[image].

**And you can drag and drop the filed inside the fieldset as you required**